# C++ Use of undeclared identifier 'make_unique'

Tags: c++, qt-creator, unique-ptr

I am keep on getting the following error when I build,

> use of undeclared identifier 'make_unique'
>          m_planet = make_unique();

My Header File which gives out the error,

```
#include "planet.h"
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

class PlanetBuilder
{
public:
    PlanetBuilder();
    virtual ~PlanetBuilder();

    void createNewPlanetProduct() {
        m_planet = make_unique<Planet>();
    }

protected:
    unique_ptr<Planet> m_planet;
};

#endif // PLANETBUILDER_H
```

I am running QtCreator 3.6.0 , tried on both Mac and Windows platforms and the error is consistent.. where am I going wrong?

Comment: [`make_unique`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique) is only available since C++14. Are you compiling with C++14 (or later) enabled (i.e. `-std=c++14` in clang or gcc)?

Comment: @Cornstalks, I'm not sure if my qt-creator is based on C++14, all I know is it uses QT_5_6_0_MinGW_32bit.. I guess it probably don't. is there any setting in qt where I can check?

Comment: Qt Creator is just an IDE, a nice visual interface for programming. Qt Creator uses a compiler behind the scenes. You should be able to enable C++14 by adding `CONFIG += c++14` (or something like that; I'm not 100% what the exact command is) in your project settings.

Answer (score 4):

make_unique requires `#include <memory>`
But since you have done that, I would think you are not using C++14 or above.
Try adding following flag on your make file.

```
-std=c++14
```

Answer (score 0):

For current QT which is 5.7 I'm using a #include .
By following a link bellow you find out more. [QScopedPointer link](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qscopedpointer.html)